# jquery: select and remove one word from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

i have a input just like below  with asal.html value

```
<input type="text" id="usernames" name="link_user" class="setinp" value="asal.html" maxlength="80" style="float:right;">
```

and i want remove .html end of value with **jquery onload** !

just like :

```
<input type="text" id="usernames" name="link_user" class="setinp" value="asal" maxlength="80" style="float:right;">
```

can you help me everyone?! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.replace`:

```
$('#usernames').val( $('#usernames').val().replace('.html',''));
```

Comment: Or `$('#usernames').val(function(_, v){ return v.replace('.html','') })`

Comment: worked !  thanks ! can you help me after that how can disable thats input? :)

Comment: set the `disabled` attribute to true

Comment: i mean in jquery :) after that :) .disabled only?

Comment: `$("#usernames").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Note that using `$('input')` in this case could be a problem if you have any other input fields on that page. They will all become disabled.